# How to stop swiper.js swiper slides moving to top onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

i have created a sliding menu that shows two items at a time. However, when the second slide in view is clicked, instead of loading in content, it puts the slide to the top of the nav and then it will load content once clicked again.

I would like the slide to load in the content and not move to the top, it does it once the slides reach the ned but i could have 20 slides in at a time.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600&display=swap');
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 990px;
    height: 1570px;
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
    font-family: open sans;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 20px #fff solid;
}
.poiIframe {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 990px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 25px;
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    border: 0px;    
}
.poiMenu {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 410px;
    height: 830px;
    bottom: 200px;
    left: 55px;
}
.swiper-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 102%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}
.poiBtn {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;    
}

.poiBtnImg {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 330px;
    height: 170px;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #F0F0F0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.poiBtnTitle {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 330px;
    height: 140px;
    top: 200px;
    left: 10px;
    color: #222;
    font-size: 2.1vh;
    display: table;
}
.poiBtnTitle  span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.poiFtr {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 25px;
    left: 50px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 990px;
    background-image: url(../img/bg/iframeFtrBg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: white;
}
.poiFtrBtn {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 20px;
    height: 122px;
    width: 138px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0;
}
.attractions {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/attractionsBtn.png);
    left: 0px;
}
.universities {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/universitiesBtn.png);
    left: 420px;
}
.hospitals {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/hospitalsBtn.png);
    left: 280px;
}
.transport {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/transportGreyBtnV2.png);
    left: 560px;
}
.entertainment {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/entertainmentBtn.png);
    left: 140px;
}
.libraries {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/librariesBtn.png);
    left: 560px;
}
.parks {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/parksBtn.png);
    left: 700px;
}
.sports {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/sportsFacilitiesBtn.png);
    left: 840px;
}
.attractionsActive {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/attractionsBtn2.png);
    left: 0px;
}
.universitiesActive {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/universitiesBtn2.png);
    left: 420px;
}
.hospitalsActive {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/hospitalsBtn2.png);
    left: 280px;
}
.transportActive {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/transportGreenBtnV2.png);
    left: 560px;
}
.entertainmentActive {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/entertainmentBtn2.png);
    left: 140px;
}
.librariesActive {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/librariesBtn2.png);
    left: 560px;
}
.parksActive {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/parksBtn2.png);
    left: 700px;
}
.sportsActive {
    background-image: url(../img/btn/NCity/sportsFacilitiesBtn2.png);
    left: 840px;
}
.swiper-vertical>.swiper-scrollbar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 1%;
    z-index: 50;
    width: 10px;
    height: 98%;
}
    .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
        background-color: #C4D000 !important;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-MZLHQBBKRP"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-MZLHQBBKRP');
</script>
<title>Notts City - Attractions</title>
<link href="../../../css/d2n2WhatsNearby.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Main POI Frame -->
<iframe class="poiIframe" name="poiIframe" src="pois/Attractions/oldMarketSquare.html"></iframe>
<!-- Info Area -->
<div class="poiMenu"> 
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper"> 
      <!-- POI 1 -->
      <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="pois/Attractions/oldMarketSquare.html" target="poiIframe">
        <div class="poiBtn">
          <div class="poiBtnImg"><img src="../../../img/pois/Old Market Square.png" /></div>
          <div class="poiBtnTitle"><span>Old Market Square</span></div>
        </div>
        </a> </div>
      <!-- POI 2 -->
      <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="pois/Attractions/nottinghamCastle.html" target="poiIframe">
        <div class="poiBtn">
          <div class="poiBtnImg"><img src="../../../img/pois/Nottingham Castle.png" /></div>
          <div class="poiBtnTitle"><span>Nottingham Castle</span></div>
        </div>
        </a> </div>
      <!-- POI 3 -->
      <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="pois/Attractions/yeOldeTripJerusalem.html" target="poiIframe">
        <div class="poiBtn">
          <div class="poiBtnImg"><img src="../../../img/pois/Ye Olde Trip to Jerusalem.png" /></div>
          <div class="poiBtnTitle"><span>Ye Olde Trip to Jerusalem</span></div>
        </div>
        </a> </div>     
      <!-- POI 5 -->
      <div class="swiper-slide"><a href="pois/Attractions/touristInfoCentre.html" target="poiIframe">
        <div class="poiBtn">
          <div class="poiBtnImg"><img src="../../../img/pois/Nottingham Tourism and Travel Centre.png" /></div>
          <div class="poiBtnTitle"><span>Tourism and Travel Centre</span></div>
        </div>
        </a> </div>     
    </div>
   <!-- <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>-->
       <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>
</div>  
<!-- Initialize Swiper -->  
<script>    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
     
    direction: 'vertical',
       slidesPerView: 2,
         spaceBetween: 60,
      freeMode: true,
   // scrollbar: {
  //   el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    //  hide: false,
   // },
        pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
      },
  })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```